# JQuery UI tooltip - opacity broken after ajax calls.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm having a following problem with jQuery UI tooltip:

Sometimes when there is an ajax call, something in the UI tooltips hangs, braking the opacity handlers.

**A scenario :** I have an inventory of items, some of them might be on cool-down, when this cool-down is finished the inventory is reloaded.

When this inventory is reloaded, the **tooltips are applied again** (reason is to apply them to the new items in inventory).

What sometimes happens is the tooltips stop working, and they get stuck with opacity:0 in the DOM. Screenshot below >

[image]

This results in no other tooltips working but ALSO anything that is supposed to change opacity (any fadeIn, fadeOut etc events) are broken as well.

Could this problem be that I reapply the tooltip after every ajax call?

Is there a way to apply the tooltips on document.ready for all the future elements as well ?(perhaps somehow with .on()?)

Few more screenshots to understand the problem are as following:

If I comment the opacity in the console.

[image]

It displays the tooltips but it still won't work.

[image]

The code I apply the tooltips with.

```
// In the done() function of the ajax call I just call
_startTooltips();

// Which does this
function _startTooltip(){

 $('.item').tooltip({
    show:{
        delay:600
        },
    items: ".item",
    content : function(){

            var element = $(this);

            if(element.is('.item')){

                return element.children('.item-tltp').html();

            }

        },
    position:{
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
    },
    track: true

 })
}
```

Comment: try applying with `!important` through CSS file.

Comment: @Era apply what with !important?

Comment: `.ui-tooltip { opacity : 1 !important}` give specific opacity to your tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Without a jsfiddle to reproduce (I understand that is difficult to isolate your scene) is not easy to figure out the cause, but as a "long shot" I'd try to remove the tooltips before you re-create them.

```
$('.item').tooltip('destroy');

$('.item').tooltip({...});
```

Comment: I have been doing something similar but in the ajax function, i have now tried to move this to the _startTooltip() function right at the beginning and so far no error. Sometimes the error show in 30 minutes sometime in 5, so ill keep on testing. Thanks!

Comment: No, its the same :( somehow the opacity handler is broken and stops handling any fadeins and fadeouts :( (or any other events where opacity is changing)